# Silverlight: template binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I'm trying to create a perfectly circular button, So I created a template from a standard button control using Expression Blend.  A normal button has the BorderThickness property of the Background object (Border Type) bound to the template using template binding.  If I wanted the border of my button to be customizable at design time, how would I bind it to the template?  It won't give me the option of binding the circles stroke thickness to the templates BorderThickness property.  I can bind a Border object's BorderThickness to the templates BorderThickness property using template binding, but I don't know how to set up the border control to always be a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to create a circle ellipse and make it a button (tools->Makebutton in expression blend.  I think this would be the simpler path.